# Jquery sortable/droppable, drop limited to one item

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

Trying to have a drop zone with only one item. Items are dragged from a sortable1 ul to a droppable ul, if there is already an item in the drop zone it must first be moved to sortable2 ul, can't get li to move to sortable2. All li will contain a table and they must retain their ids.

http://jsfiddle.net/qLS4s/6/

```
$("#drop_zone").droppable({
accept: ".connectedSortable li",
hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
drop: function (ev, ui) {
  var drop_id = String('#').concat(jQuery(ui.helper).attr("id"));

  $("#drop_zone li").each(function(index, item) {
  var drop_zone_id = jQuery(item).attr("id");
  if (typeof(drop_zone_li_id) != "undefined")
  {
    if (drop_zone_li_id != '' && drop_zone_li_id != drop_id)
    {
      $(drop_zone_li_id).appendTo('#sortable2'); // This should move item but doesn't
    }  
  }    
  });

  $("<li></li>").html(ui.draggable.html()).appendTo(this);
  ui.draggable.remove();
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

All these string/id manipulations are rather confusing and completely unnecessary. You're overcomplicating it: you can simply `.appendTo(otherParent)` all the children in the `drop` event (especially since you're rejecting all natural drops and manually re-creating each element). All you need is something like this:

```
$("#drop_zone li").appendTo('#sortable2');
```

Here's an example update: http://jsfiddle.net/z9Ad9/

Comment: From lack of understanding comes over complication, is there a way to keep the id with the li though?